# Is it possible to get position in Canvas where canvas is a css fixed element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Right now when I set position: absolute; in css it gives:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
    at HTMLCanvasElement.getColor
```

It works when position: absolute; But I need the Canvas in fixed position.

My findPos() function to get the position of object:

```js
function findPos(obj) {
  var curleft = 0, curtop = 0;
  if (obj.offsetParent) {
    do {
      curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
      curtop += obj.offsetTop;
    } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

Please check the fiddle for my code: https://jsfiddle.net/ds6kug6r/8/

Comment: Seems that chrome nullifies `.offsetParent` of fixed positioned elements, which makes sense to me. Why do you even try to get through all previous parents anyway? Ps: FF doesn't, so one might be wrong, and according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLelement/offsetParent#Compatibility), Chrome is right.

Comment: @Kaiido - I found that issue too., but don't have any solution to the problem. Can you suggest a better option to get the position where I don't have to use .offsetParent ?

Comment: What does your code actually do? Do you have lots of canvas elements with fixed position? Why?

Comment: @KokodokoThanks for the reply. Please check jsfiddle. I have only one canvas. I want that to be fixed position. So, it doesn't disappear when I scroll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because according to [the specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-htmlelement-offsetparent) (**2.1**), fixed positioned elements don't have an `offsetParent` element.

But you don't need it anyway, instead use [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) which doesn't suffer from the padding edge issue.

```js
function getColor(e) {
  // getBoundingClientRect to retrieve the position of our canvas in the doc
  var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  // we also need to use clientX and clientY values now
  var x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  var y = e.clientY - rect.top;
  var coord = "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
  var c = this.getContext('2d');
  var p = c.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
  log(p);
}


/* Color Wheel */
var canvas = document.getElementById("picker");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width / 2;
var y = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 100;
var counterClockwise = false;

for (var angle = 0; angle <= 360; angle += 1) {
  var startAngle = (angle - 2) * Math.PI / 180;
  var endAngle = angle * Math.PI / 180;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x, y);
  context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
  var gradient = context.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0, x, y, radius);
  gradient.addColorStop(0, 'hsl(' + angle + ', 10%, 100%)');
  gradient.addColorStop(1, 'hsl(' + angle + ', 100%, 50%)');
  context.fillStyle = gradient;
  context.fill();
}


document.getElementById("picker").addEventListener("click", getColor);


function log(m) {
  document.getElementById("viz").style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(' + m + ')';
  document.getElementById("log").append(m + '\n')
}
```

```css
canvas {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#viz {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="colorWheel" id="picker" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

<div>
  Log: <span id="viz"></span>
  <pre id="log"></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: there's an issue though. It only works until I scroll down. If I scroll down then it stops working

Comment: @tareqanwar right, didn't saw you were using `pageY`, needs to be `clientY`.